# Why is Activity Indicator Showing Twice

Tags: uitableview, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm implementing an activity indicator to show while the image is fetched/loads. However, the activity indicator sometimes shows up twice in the same frame.

I checked the code numerous times and even tried other methods such as a counter matching the row number. Any idea why this is showing up twice? (see image below)

**Activity Indicator Code (inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`):**

```
 // start indicator when loading images
 var indicatorPhoto: MaterialActivityIndicatorView! = MaterialActivityIndicatorView(style: .Small)
 indicatorPhoto.center = cell.mainRestaurantImageView.center
 cell.mainRestaurantImageView.addSubview(indicatorPhoto)
 indicatorPhoto!.startAnimating()

 cell.mainRestaurantImageView.loadInBackground {
      (success: UIImage!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
      if ((success) != nil) {
           // stop indicator when loading images
           if indicatorPhoto?.isAnimating == true {
                 indicatorPhoto!.stopAnimating()
                 indicatorPhoto!.removeFromSuperview()
           }
      } else {
           println("Unsuccessful Fetch Image")
           if indicatorPhoto?.isAnimating == true {
                indicatorPhoto!.stopAnimating()
                indicatorPhoto!.removeFromSuperview()
           }
      }
 }
```

[image]

#### Update:

This is the rest of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RestaurantCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FeedCell

        cell.nameLabel.text = restaurantNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.photoNameLabel.text = photoNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.cityLabel.text = " " + addressCity[indexPath.row]
        cell.distanceLabel?.text = arrayRoundedDistances[indexPath.row] + "mi"

        // check if there are images
        if foodPhotoObjects.isEmpty {  } else {
            var restaurantArrayData = self.foodPhotoObjects[indexPath.row] as PFObject
            cell.mainRestaurantImageView.image = UIImage(named: "") // set placeholder
            cell.mainRestaurantImageView.file = restaurantArrayData["SmPhotoUploaded"] as PFFile

            // start indicator when loading images
            var indicatorPhoto: MaterialActivityIndicatorView! = MaterialActivityIndicatorView(style: .Small)
            indicatorPhoto.center = cell.mainRestaurantImageView.center
            cell.mainRestaurantImageView.addSubview(indicatorPhoto)
            indicatorPhoto!.startAnimating()

            cell.mainRestaurantImageView.loadInBackground {
                (success: UIImage!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if ((success) != nil) {
                    // stop indicator when loading images
                    if indicatorPhoto?.isAnimating == true {
                        indicatorPhoto!.stopAnimating()
                        indicatorPhoto!.removeFromSuperview()
                    }
                } else {
                    println("Unsuccessful Fetch Image")
                    if indicatorPhoto?.isAnimating == true {
                        indicatorPhoto!.stopAnimating()
                        indicatorPhoto!.removeFromSuperview()
                    }
                }
            }

            cell.mainRestaurantImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
            cell.mainRestaurantImageView.clipsToBounds = true

        }

        return cell
    }
```

#### Update 2

```
// create indicator when loading images
        var indicatorPhoto : MaterialActivityIndicatorView? = cell.mainRestaurantImageView.viewWithTag(123) as? MaterialActivityIndicatorView;
        if indicatorPhoto == nil{
            indicatorPhoto = MaterialActivityIndicatorView(style: .Small)
            indicatorPhoto!.center = cell.mainRestaurantImageView.center
            indicatorPhoto!.tag = 123
            cell.mainRestaurantImageView.addSubview(indicatorPhoto!)
            indicatorPhoto!.startAnimating()
        }
```

Comment: Not sure if it's causing this issue but you have a cell reuse bug. In your completion handlers you're assuming that the cell hasn't been recycled, but it may have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is showing multiple times because you're adding it multiple times. In fact every time when the else case of `foodPhotoObjects.isEmpty` is called.

This is because, the first line of your method:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("RestaurantCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FeedCell
```

dequeues the cell from table view. The dequeue works as follow:

1. It maintains a queue based on the identifier.
2. If there's no cell in the queue, it creates a new cell.
3. If there's already a cell, it returns that cell to you. Which will be re-used.

So what you're doing is, you're adding `MaterialActivityIndicatorView` every time to the cell, whether it was added previously or not.

**Solution:**

1. Add a custom view to your cell from xib, and set its class to
   `MaterialActivityIndicatorView`. And get the reference here to
   hide/show and animation.
2. Check the sub-views of `cell.mainRestaurantImageView` and see if
   there's already a `MaterialActivityIndicatorView`, get its reference
   and do animation and stuff. If there's no subview as `MaterialActivityIndicatorView`, create one and add it to the image view as subview. You'll use the tag property for this.

The second approach can be done something like this:

```
//first find the activity indication with tag 123, if its found, cast it to its proper class
var indicatorPhoto : MaterialActivityIndicatorView? = cell.mainRestaurantImageView.viewWithTag(123) as? MaterialActivityIndicatorView;
if indicatorPhoto == nil{
    //seems it wasn't found as subview initialize here and add to mainRestaurantImageView with tag 123
}
//do rest of the stuff.
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm trying approach 2 (see Update 2 in original question). It seems the answer gets rid of the duplicate indicators, but it is still showing the loading indicator on the right (not centered). Did I implement it incorrectly?

Comment: That's because you're adding it as subview to `cell.mainRestaurantImageView`. You need to review the placing of `cell.mainRestaurantImageView`, if that's centered properly, then the indicator will center itself correctly.

Comment: That did it. I centered the x around the frame instead of the imageview.